# How to replace the task definition revision number with wild card in EventPattern taskDefinitionArn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-event-bridge, cloudwatch-alarms

The following code is working as expected.But,It did not work when I replaced the revision number 2 with wild card * since I want work for current revision number which can be any number. "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:*********:task-definition/test-definition-task:*"

Can anyone suggest the better approach so that it will work for the current revision?

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "taskDefinitionArn": [
      "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:*********:task-definition/test-definition-task:2"
    ],
    "stoppedReason": [
      "Essential container in task exited"
    ],
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik EB does not support wildcards. Instead you can use a [`prefix`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-prefix-matching) pattern:

```
"taskDefinitionArn": [
  { "prefix": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:*********:task-definition/test-definition-task:" }
],
```